# EnQuireR package for questionnaire analysis

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to explore EnQuireR package for questionnaire analysis (for tea data). But ENbarplot & XvsYbarplot gives error:

```
ENbarplot(tea, 20, numr=1, numc=1, spl=TRUE)
Error in hsv(h = a * m, s = 0.4 + (cont[j]/max) * 0.6, v = 1, 1, 1) : 
unused argument (1)
```

&

```
XvsYbarplot("socio.professional.category","sex",tea, legend.text=TRUE)  
Error in hsv(h = a * i, s = 1, v = 1, 1, 1) : unused argument (1)
```

Also, I am facing problems in interpreting the output of chisq.desc() function. Does colored cells represent significant association between corresponding variables? Can anyone please explain in detail?

Comment: Even running the example of `ENbarplot` leads to an error. Maybe time to contact the maintainer: `maintainer("EnQuireR")`. It wouldn't be surprising that something is broken, as the package wasn't updated for almost 6 years. At this time, the version of R was `2.11.1`.

Comment: @Pascal, Thanks. Can you also help me interpret the output of chisq.desc() function?

Comment: https://github.com/cran/EnQuireR/blob/master/R/tab_chi2.R. The function is using `coltable` function from `SensoMineR`. Please read the help file.

Comment: @Pascal, I've already explored this link and any other related stuff, which I could google. But I am new to it. It's description says, chisq.desc() function Color the cells of the table containing the results from the Chi-square test, crossing all the selected categorical variables, according to a selected threshold. But I couldn't understand it. Can you please help me understand the output of     chisq.desc(tea, 13:17,31:35)?

Comment: I told you to read the help page of coltable.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Earlier, I was afraid looking at long codes in cran repository & searched a lot but couldn't find it. But I realized that the output shows the chi-squared values and colored cells shows significant association between the variables.

Comment: I was trying to modify the code of the package. Only partly could resolve the errors.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the hsv function in the graphic devices utilities. There is an extra argument passed the function making it to fail. I tried fixing it. The code below should work if you're still interested in using the package

```
barplot_function1 <- function (dataset, X, spl = FALSE, numr = NULL, numc = NULL, 
                              cex = 1, colour = NULL) 
{
        mult = length(X)
        col = rep(0)
        count_mod <- rep(0)
        a <- 1/mult
        for (m in 1:mult) {
                if (spl) {
                        cont <- sort(table(dataset[, X[m]]))
                }
                else {
                        cont <- table(dataset[, X[m]])
                }
                NR <- dim(cont)
                count_mod <- c(count_mod, NR)
                max <- max(cont)
                coli <- rep(0, NR)
                for (j in 1:NR) {
                        if (cont[j] == max) {
                                coli[j] <- hsv(h = a * m, s = 1, v = 1, 1)
                        }
                        else {
                                coli[j] <- hsv(h = a * m, s = 0.4 + (cont[j]/max) * 
                                                       0.6, v = 1, 1)
                        }
                }
                col <- c(col, coli)
        }
        col <- col[-1]
        count_mod <- count_mod[-1]
        summ <- cumsum(count_mod)
        na = matrix(0, 1, mult)
        if (is.null(numr)) {
                if (is.null(numc)) {
                        numr = numc = 2
                }
        }
        par(mfrow = c(numr, numc), yaxt = "n")
        tpolice <- par("cex")
        par(xpd = T, mar = par()$mar + c(0, 1, 0, 0))
        for (m in 1:mult) {
                for (i in 1:((dim(dataset)[2])/(numr * numc))) {
                        if (m == ((numr * numc) * i) + 1) {
                                x11()
                                par(mfrow = c(numr, numc), yaxt = "n")
                        }
                }
                k = 0
                for (i in 1:length(dataset[, X[m]])) {
                        if ((is.na(dataset[, X[m]])[[i]]) == TRUE) {
                                k = k + 1
                        }
                }
                na[m] = k/length(dataset[, X[m]])
                if (spl == TRUE) {
                        coord = barplot(sort(table(dataset[, X[m]])), beside = TRUE, 
                                        las = 2, horiz = TRUE, main = names(dataset)[X[m]], 
                                        col = col[(summ[m] - count_mod[m] + 1:summ[m])])
                        text(x = 2, y = coord, labels = names(sort(table(dataset[, 
                                                                                 X[m]]))), adj = 0, cex = cex, col = colour)
                }
                if (spl == FALSE) {
                        coord = barplot(table(dataset[, X[m]]), beside = TRUE, 
                                        las = 2, horiz = TRUE, main = names(dataset)[X[m]], 
                                        col = col[(summ[m] - count_mod[m] + 1:summ[m])])
                        text(x = 2, y = coord, labels = levels(dataset[, 
                                                                       X[m]]), adj = 0, cex = cex, col = colour)
                }
                mtext(paste(c("Percentage of missing values  =", round(na[m], 
                                                                       2) * 100, "%"), collapse = " "), side = 3, line = -0.1, 
                      cex = tpolice, adj = 0)
        }
}

ENbarplotfixed <- function (dataset, X, spl = FALSE, numr = NULL, numc = NULL, 
                       report = FALSE) 
{
        if (report == FALSE) {
                barplot_function1(dataset, X, spl, numr, numc)
        }
        if `enter code here`(report == TRUE) {
                assign("X", X, envir = .GlobalEnv)
                assign("dataset", dataset, envir = .GlobalEnv)
                a = getwd()
                dir.create(paste(a, "/EnQuireR/", sep = ""))
                file.copy(paste(.libPaths()[1], "/EnQuireR/Sweave/sty/fancyvrb.sty", 
                                sep = ""), paste(a, "/EnQuireR/fancyvrb.sty", sep = ""))
                file.copy(paste(.libPaths()[1], "/EnQuireR/Sweave/sty/Sweave.sty", 
                                sep = ""), paste(a, "/EnQuireR/Sweave.sty", sep = ""))
                file.copy(paste(.libPaths()[1], "/EnQuireR/Sweave/sty/upquote.sty", 
                                sep = ""), paste(a, "/EnQuireR/upquote.sty", sep = ""))
                file.copy(paste(.libPaths()[1], "/EnQuireR/Sweave/sty/algorithmic.sty", 
                                sep = ""), paste(a, "/EnQuireR/algorithmic.sty", 
                                                 sep = ""))
                setwd(paste(a, "/EnQuireR", sep = ""))
                Sweave(paste(.libPaths()[1], "/EnQuireR/Sweave/barplot/Univariate_report.Rnw", 
                             sep = ""), driver = RweaveLatex(), syntax = getOption("SweaveSyntax"))
                tools::texi2dvi(paste(a, "/EnQuireR/Univariate_report.tex", 
                                      sep = ""), pdf = TRUE)
                setwd(a)
        }
}

#plot
ENbarplotfixed(tea,20,spl=T,numr=1,numc=1)

#plot upon condition
XvsYbarplotfixed <- XvsYbarplotfixed <- function (var1, var2, dataset, width = 1, space = NULL, names.arg = NULL, 
                                                  legend.text = NULL, horiz = FALSE, density = NULL, angle = 45, 
                                                  col = NULL, border = par("fg"), main = NULL, sub = NULL, 
                                                  xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, xpd = TRUE, 
                                                  log = "", axes = TRUE, axisnames = TRUE, cex.axis = par("cex.axis"), 
                                                  cex.names = par("cex.axis"), inside = TRUE, plot = TRUE, 
                                                  axis.lty = 0, offset = 0, add = FALSE, ...) 
{
        dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
        if (is.character(var1) & is.character(var2)) {
                num_var1 <- match(var1, names(dataset))
                num_var2 <- match(var2, names(dataset))
                height <- table(dataset[, num_var1], dataset[, num_var2])
        }
        else {
                height <- table(var1, var2)
        }
        if (!missing(inside)) 
                .NotYetUsed("inside", error = FALSE)
        if (is.null(space)) 
                space <- if (is.matrix(height)) 
                        c(0, 1)
        else 0.2
        space <- space * mean(width)
        if (plot && axisnames && is.null(names.arg)) 
                names.arg <- if (is.matrix(height)) 
                        colnames(height)
        else names(height)
        if (is.vector(height) || (is.array(height) && (length(dim(height)) == 
                                                       1))) {
                height <- cbind(height)
                if (is.null(col)) 
                        if (is.null(col)) 
                                col <- rep(0)
                        NR <- length(height)
                        max <- max(height)
                        for (i in 1:NR) {
                                if (height[i] == max) {
                                        coli <- hsv(h = 1, s = 1, v = 1, 1)
                                        col <- cbind(col, coli)
                                }
                                else {
                                        coli <- hsv(h = 1, s = 0.4 + (height[i]/max) * 
                                                            0.6, v = 1, 1)
                                        col <- c(col, coli)
                                }
                        }
                        col <- col[-1]
        }
        else if (is.matrix(height)) {
                if (is.null(col)) 
                        NR <- nrow(height)
                NC <- ncol(height)
                col = rep(0)
                a <- 1/NC
                for (i in 1:NC) {
                        max <- max(height[, i])
                        coli <- rep(0, NR)
                        for (j in 1:NR) {
                                if (height[j, i] == max) {
                                        coli[j] <- hsv(h = a * i, s = 1, v = 1, 1)
                                }
                                else {
                                        coli[j] <- hsv(h = a * i, s = 0.4 + (height[j, 
                                                                                    i]/max) * 0.6, v = 1, 1)
                                }
                        }
                        col <- c(col, coli)
                }
                col <- col[-1]
        }
        else stop("'height' must be a vector or a matrix")
        if (is.logical(legend.text)) 
                legend.text <- if (legend.text && is.matrix(height)) 
                        rownames(height)
        stopifnot(is.character(log))
        logx <- logy <- FALSE
        if (log != "") {
                logx <- length(grep("x", log)) > 0L
                logy <- length(grep("y", log)) > 0L
        }
        if ((logx || logy) && !is.null(density)) 
                stop("Cannot use shading lines in bars when log scale is used")
        NR <- nrow(height)
        NC <- ncol(height)
        if (length(space) == 2) 
                space <- rep.int(c(space[2], rep.int(space[1], NR - 1)), 
                                 NC)
        width <- rep(width, length.out = NR)
        offset <- rep(as.vector(offset), length.out = length(width))
        delta <- width/2
        w.r <- cumsum(space + width)
        w.m <- w.r - delta
        w.l <- w.m - delta
        log.dat <- (logx && horiz) || (logy && !horiz)
        if (log.dat) {
                if (min(height + offset, na.rm = TRUE) <= 0) 
                        stop("log scale error: at least one 'height + offset' value <= 0")
                if (logx && !is.null(xlim) && min(xlim) <= 0) 
                        stop("log scale error: 'xlim' <= 0")
                if (logy && !is.null(ylim) && min(ylim) <= 0) 
                        stop("log scale error: 'ylim' <= 0")
                rectbase <- if (logy && !horiz && !is.null(ylim)) 
                        ylim[1]
                else if (logx && horiz && !is.null(xlim)) 
                        xlim[1]
                else 0.9 * min(height, na.rm = TRUE)
        }
        else rectbase <- 0
        rAdj <- offset + (if (log.dat) 
                0.9 * height
                else -0.01 * height)
        delta <- width/2
        w.r <- cumsum(space + width)
        w.m <- w.r - delta
        w.l <- w.m - delta
        num_mod <- nlevels(var1)
        if (horiz) {
                if (is.null(xlim)) 
                        xlim <- range(rAdj, height + offset, na.rm = TRUE)
                if (is.null(ylim)) 
                        ylim <- c(min(w.l), max(w.r) + num_mod + (num_mod - 
                                                                          1))
        }
        else {
                if (is.null(xlim)) 
                        xlim <- c(min(w.l), max(w.r))
                if (is.null(ylim)) 
                        ylim <- range(rAdj, height + offset + num_mod * 5, 
                                      na.rm = TRUE)
        }
        w.m <- matrix(w.m, ncol = NC)
        par(mar = par("mar") + c(1, 0, 0, 0))
        if (plot) {
                opar <- if (horiz) 
                        par(xaxs = "i", xpd = xpd)
                else par(yaxs = "i", xpd = xpd)
                on.exit(par(opar))
                if (!add) {
                        plot.new()
                        if (horiz) {
                                if (is.character(attributes(var1)$levels) == 
                                    TRUE) {
                                        if (max(nchar(attributes(var1)$levels)) > 8) {
                                                par(mar = par("mar") + c(0, round(max(nchar(attributes(var1)$levels))/3), 
                                                                         0, 0))
                                        }
                                }
                                else {
                                        par(mar = par("mar") + c(0, 5, 0, 0))
                                }
                                plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...)
                        }
                        else plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...)
                }
                xyrect <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2, horizontal = TRUE, 
                                   ...) {
                        if (horizontal) 
                                rect(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...)
                        else rect(y1, x1, y2, x2, ...)
                }
                xyrect(rectbase + offset, w.l, c(height) + offset, w.r, 
                       horizontal = horiz, angle = angle, density = density, 
                       col = col, border = border)
                if (axisnames && !is.null(names.arg)) {
                        at.l <- if (length(names.arg) != length(w.m)) {
                                if (length(names.arg) == NC) 
                                        colMeans(w.m)
                                else stop("incorrect number of names")
                        }
                        else w.m
                        if (!horiz) 
                                if (is.character(attributes(var1)$levels) == 
                                    TRUE) {
                                        for (i in 1:nlevels(var2)) {
                                                if (nchar(attributes(var2)$levels[i]) > 11) 
                                                        names.arg[i] <- substring(attributes(var2)$levels[i], 
                                                                                  1, 11)
                                        }
                                }
                        if (horiz) {
                                axis(2, at = at.l, labels = names.arg, lty = axis.lty, 
                                     cex.axis = cex.names, las = 2)
                        }
                        else {
                                axis(1, at = at.l, labels = names.arg, lty = axis.lty, 
                                     cex.axis = cex.names, las = 0)
                        }
                }
                if (!is.null(legend.text)) {
                        legend.col <- rep(col, length.out = length(legend.text))
                        if (!horiz) {
                                legend.text <- legend.text
                                legend.col <- legend.col
                                density <- rev(density)
                                angle <- rev(angle)
                        }
                        num.legend <- c("1st", "2nd", "3rd")
                        for (i in 4:20) {
                                num.legendi <- c(paste(i, "th"))
                                num.legend <- c(num.legend, num.legendi)
                        }
                        num.legend <- num.legend[1:dim(height)[1]]
                        xy <- par("usr")
                        if (horiz) {
                                legend2(xy[2] - xinch(0.1), xy[4] - yinch(0.1), 
                                        legend = paste(num.legend, "bar:", legend.text), 
                                        angle = angle, density = density, fill = legend.col, 
                                        bty = "n", cex = 1 - 0.04 * num_mod, xjust = 1, 
                                        yjust = 1)
                        }
                        else {
                                legend2(xy[2] - xinch(0.1), xy[4] - yinch(0.1), 
                                        legend = paste(num.legend, "bar:", legend.text), 
                                        angle = angle, density = density, fill = legend.col, 
                                        bty = "n", xjust = 1, yjust = 1)
                        }
                }
                if (is.character(var1) & is.character(var2)) {
                        title(main = paste(names(dataset[num_var1]), "depending on", 
                                           names(dataset[num_var2])), sub = sub, xlab = xlab, 
                              ylab = ylab, ...)
                }
                else {
                        for (i in 1:length(dataset)) {
                                a <- match(var1, dataset[, i])
                                b <- match(var2, dataset[, i])
                                if (any(is.na(a)) == FALSE) {
                                        rep1 = i
                                }
                                if (any(is.na(b)) == FALSE) {
                                        rep2 = i
                                }
                        }
                        title(main = paste(names(dataset[rep1]), "depending on", 
                                           names(dataset[rep2])), sub = sub, xlab = xlab, 
                              ylab = ylab, ...)
                }
                if (axes) 
                        if (horiz) {
                                axis(1, cex.axis = cex.axis, las = 0, ...)
                        }
                else {
                        axis(2, cex.axis = cex.axis, las = 2, ...)
                }
                invisible(w.m)
        }
        else w.m
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how should I use it?